# How to override the function which is not assigned to $scope in a angular.module.controller

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a tampermonkey script to change the implement of a angular controller.The source javascript code running behind the matched page is below.

```
angular.module('xxx.xxx.controllers', [])
    .controller('xxxCtrl', function($scope, ...) {
        ...
        $scope.fnToBeOverrided1 = function(a, b) {

            // do something.
        }
        
        function anotherFnToBeOverrided(a, b) {
            // do something.
        }
        ...
    })
```

and I have successfully changed the behavior of $scope.fnToBeOverrided with angular decorator.

```
angular.module('xxx.xxx.controllers')
    .decorator('$controller', function ($delegate) {
        return function (constructor, locals) {      
            if (typeof locals.$scope.fnToBeOverrided1 !== 'undefined') {
                locals.$scope.fnToBeOverrided1 = function() {
                    // changed the behavior of $scope.fnToBeOverrided1
                }
            }
            var controller = $delegate.apply(constructor, arguments);
            return controller;
        };
    });
```

But if the anotherFnToBeOverided(a, b) is not assinged to $scope.How can i do to change it's behavior?